# How do browsers decide when to open a new connection when using HTTP/1.1?

Tags: google-chrome, http, networking, http-1.1

In HTTP/1.1, browsers will open multiple TCP sessions in parallel to speed up the loading process. For example, in the screenshot chrome opens 5 connections in total.
[image: Network waterfall recorded by DevTools]
My question is, how does a browser like Chrome decide when to open a new connection and when to reuse an existing connection? For example, in the screenshot, why didn't the browser open a new connection for main.css, when its priority is higher than main.js who got a new connection opened for it?